# Ruby. Troubles with concerns

Tags: ruby

Написал модуль со множеством методов и каждый мой метод начинается с одного и того же кода и я попытался написать консерн для этого, но не смог сделать этого. Модуль в модуль не подтягивается почему-то.

```
require 'concerns/passparameters'

module Test
 def self.connect(win_ip, win_user, win_password)
  include Parseparameters
  parse(win_ip, win_user, win_password)

  arr = []
  conn [... some code ...]
end

module Parseparameters
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    include do
    url = URI.parse("http://#{win_ip}:5985/wsman")
    opts = {
      endpoint: url,
      user: win_user,
      password: win_password,
      disable_sspi: true
     }
  conn = WinRM::Connection.new(opts)
 end    
end
```

Как результат получаю то, что переменная conn не определена

Comment: You are st the Russian servers :)

Comment: conn должно быть методом, а не переменной. И инклудить нужно не в метод, а в сам модуль. Хук правильно пишется `included do`